# WebRTC wssURL and ICE Setup

Tags: websocket, webrtc, ice

I'm trying to build an app that will need to be able to connect multiple peers together over WebRTC.

I'm working from the example at: https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc

I'm stuck on how to setup what is needed for the following 4 lines of code:

```
  iceServerRequestUrl: '{{ ice_server_url }}',
  iceServerTransports: '{{ ice_server_transports }}',
  wssUrl: '{{ wss_url }}',
  wssPostUrl: '{{ wss_post_url }}',
```

That would be part of this section of loading parameters:

```
var loadingParams = {
  errorMessages: [],
  isLoopback: false,
  warningMessages: [],    
  mediaConstraints: {"audio": true, "video": {"optional": [{"minWidth": "1280"}, {"minHeight": "720"}], "mandatory": {}}},
  offerOptions: {},
  peerConnectionConfig: {"rtcpMuxPolicy": "require", "bundlePolicy": "max-bundle", "iceServers": []},
  peerConnectionConstraints: {"optional": []},
  iceServerRequestUrl: '{{ ice_server_url }}',
  iceServerTransports: '{{ ice_server_transports }}',
  wssUrl: '{{ wss_url }}',
  wssPostUrl: '{{ wss_post_url }}',
  bypassJoinConfirmation: false,
  versionInfo: {"gitHash": "06b18b54af995bab9e16c2648ddb7edbbe553541", "branch": "master", "time": "Mon Sep 14 17:52:24 2020 +0200"},

};
```

I understand that a web socket is needed, but I'm unsure how to set this up for a web app. I'm working with cPanel.

How do I set up the iceServerRequestUrl, iceServerTransports, wssUrl, and wssPostUrl?

Comment: Take a look at OpenVidu, it have similar stuff => WebRTC with kurento, coturn, etc... https://openvidu.io/index try the demo there and you sill wee

Comment: I just looked into openvidu and it looks like it's for on-prem only. Any advice for trying to build a web app?

Comment: What do you mean by "on-prem" ? you install OpenVidu in a server and then you can iframe it in a regular webpage. You can control OpenVidu via API calls and weebhooks are available too. It's also customizable. Plus ; it's compatible within a webView on Android and iPhone and you can make a mobile app too. I'm developing web apps and mobile apps and I see lots of good stuff with OpenVidu. Plus the team that develop this is easily reachable, you can email them at info@openvidu.io if you have any questions.